# Messed up BackStage with Universal App (Windows Phone 8.1)

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm having problems with the Navigation in my windows phone 8.1 part of a universal app I created. I'll try to explain.

I have the following (sorry my spacing/tabbing appears to be messed up below!)

```
1) Home Page (click on a + on the app bar and it navigates to 2)
  ->> 2) New Item Page (click on the image preview and it navigates to 3)
    ->> 3) Capture Page (tap on a button)
      ->> From Cam button (not implemented)
       ->> From Photo button
          ->> 4) Select from album or Take a photo
         [- -----Tap Accept and it goes back to New Item (2) and 
                 display the photo as a preview.
```

But when I click on the back key, it should technically bring me back 
to my Home Page(1) but instead it does the following:

```
   First back press: Goes back to Capture Page (3)
   Second back press: Goes back to New Item Page (2)
   Third back press: Goes back to Home (1)
```

I'm using the WP File Picker to select a photo, but whether I select 
one or press the back key, it goes to my OnActivated event located in
my App.xaml.cs

In the async Method (WPPickedFile) which is called when selecting a 
photo or pressing the back key, it checks if args.Files.Count has 
returned a photo or not and I've added the following lines of code to 
see if it would make a difference:

`if (((Frame)Window.Current.Content).BackStackDepth > 2)
  ((Frame)Window.Current.Content).BackStack.Remove(((Frame)
   Window.Current.Content).BackStack[2]);

if (((Frame)Window.Current.Content).BackStackDepth > 1)
    ((Frame)Window.Current.Content).BackStack.Remove(((Frame)
    Window.Current.Content).BackStack[1]);`

but it doesn't make one bit of difference. If I press the back key 
instead of selecting a photo, my `BackStageDepth` is 2 and it 
contains the Home Page (1) and New Item Page (2). If I select a photo, 
it contains these 2 and it also contains the Capture Page (3).

But here is the weird behaviour I don't get. Assume that I press the back 
key and did not select a photo. My `BackStageDepth` is 2 and contains only 
the Home Page (1) and the New Item Page (2) so when I get the the lines
described above, it skips the one with > 2 and it removes the New Item 
Page (2). When I check it is removed and my `BackStageDepth` has dropped to 1.

This is not what I want to achieve but I'm trying to understand what's 
going on. Anyway, when I continue running the code, I get my New Item Page (2)
displayed and my preview image remains empty since I pressed the back key 
on the WP File Picker.

Now the strange is that when I press the back key once again, I put a 
break point on the `HardwareButtons_BackPressed` which is located in 
the NavigationHelper but if I check (Frame)
Window.Current.Content).BackStackDepth, it's now telling me that it 2 
rather than 1. If I check it, `(Frame)Window.Current.Content).BackStack[0]` 
is still my Home Page (1) but `(Frame)Window.Current.Content).BackStack[1]` 
is now set to the Capture Page (3) which wasn't listed when I checked it
in the method `WPPickedFile`.

Why is that? I'm totally confused but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong but it's obviously related to the fact that I'm leaving the app when the WP File Picker is launched as if I don't i.e. go from Home Page(1) to 
Capture Page (3) without clicking on the button to launch the WP File Picker,
the navigation works as expected.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Thanks.

PS: Sorry for the poor formatting but I couldn't fix it!

Answer (score 0):

My backstack wasn't actually messed up. I found out the hard way that windows phone 8.1 could have multiple frames and I totally

In regards to navigating back to the previous page before the one that's calling the FilePicker, I finally figured out a way, which appears to be clean and doesn't call the nagivation and therefore the page to the backstack

```
#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
    protected async override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnActivated(e);

        continuationManager = new ContinuationManager();

        Frame rootFrame = CreateRootFrame();
        await RestoreStatusAsync(e.PreviousExecutionState);

        if (rootFrame.Content == null)
        {
            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(LocationsPage));
        }

        var continuationEventArgs = e as IContinuationActivatedEventArgs;
        if (continuationEventArgs != null)
        {
            if (rootFrame.Content is CaptureTypePage)
            {
                if (rootFrame.CanGoBack)
                    rootFrame.GoBack();
            }
            // Call ContinuationManager to handle continuation activation
            continuationManager.Continue(continuationEventArgs, rootFrame);
        }

        Window.Current.Activate();
    }

#endif
```

The important part is:

```
if (rootFrame.Content is CaptureTypePage)
{
  if (rootFrame.CanGoBack)
    rootFrame.GoBack();
}
```

continuationManager.Continue(continuationEventArgs, rootFrame);

By calling the `GoBack`, it removes the CaptureTypePage and sets the `CurrentSourcePageType` of the rootFrame to the 'New Item Page' where the preview window is.

I then implemented the interface `IFileOpenPickerContinuable` on the 'New Item Page' and this is called by the continuationManager.Continue function i.e.

```
case ActivationKind.PickSaveFileContinuation:
  var fileSavePickerPage = rootFrame.Content as IFileSavePickerContinuable;
  if (fileSavePickerPage != null)
  {
    fileSavePickerPage.ContinueFileSavePicker(args as 
    FileSavePickerContinuationEventArgs);
  }
  break;
```

I hope this helps someone else and won't waste time the way I did! If you have a cleaner way of doing this, please add to this post. I'd love to know.

Thanks.